# Using a timeout to simulate a spinner

Tags: javascript

I am going deep on this array in order to make an `id` comparison. I want to know if there is a way to use like a kind of flatten function to avoid using `_.each` the way I am using it because I think it is not a good practice.

.json file:

```
[
  {
    "enterprise" : [
      {
        "id" : "743512",
        "name" : "Hellen Quesada",
        "role" : "P. Software Engineer",
        "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
        "skype" : "he.quesada",
        "email" : "hquesada1@publicisgroupe.net",
        "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
        "subDept" : "Enterprise",
        "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
      },
      {
        "id" : "743587",
        "name" : "Jonathan Chavez",
        "role" : "P. Creative Engineer",
        "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
        "skype" : "jonathanchavesb",
        "email" : "jonathan.chaves@prodigious.cr",
        "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
        "subDept" : "Enterprise",
        "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
      },
      {
        "id" : "749058",
        "name" : "Rodrigo Ovares",
        "role" : "Creative Engineer",
        "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
        "skype" : "rodrigo.ovares.arroyo",
        "email" : "rodrigo.ovares@publicisgroupe.net",
        "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
        "subDept" : "Enterprise",
        "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
      },
      {
        "id" : "750684",
        "name" : "Juan Morera",
        "role" : "Software Engineer",
        "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
        "skype" : "morerajuan",
        "email" : "juan.morera@prodigious.cr",
        "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
        "subDept" : "Enterprise",
        "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
      }
    ]
  },
"consumer" : [
  {
    "id" : "743360",
    "name" : "Leroy Bernard",
    "role" : "Sr. Software Engineer",
    "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
    "skype" : "leroy.bernard.cr",
    "email" : "leroy.bernard@email.com",
    "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
    "subDept" : "Consumer",
    "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
  },
  {
    "id" : "765434",
    "name" : "Helga Martinez",
    "role" : "Production Manager",
    "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
    "skype" : "helga.martinez.cr",
    "email" : "helga.martinez@digitaslbi.com",
    "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
    "subDept" : "Consumer",
    "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
  },
  {
    "id" : "764954",
    "name" : "Marvin Solano",
    "role" : "Sr. Frontend Engineer",
    "picture" : "http://i276.photobucket.com/albums/kk35/Sicable/200x200/06.png",
    "skype" : "mase9207",
    "email" : "marvin.solano@prodigious.com",
    "account" : "Digitas, Flag",
    "subDept" : "Consumer",
    "location" : "Offshore: Costa Rica"
    }
   ]
  }
]
```

I am calling this function every time I need to compare an `id`:

```
  var compareId = function(id, evt) {
    $('.spinner, .while-loads').fadeIn();
    var cardTemplate = [],
        getData = localStorage.getItem('jsonData'),
        json = JSON.parse(getData);

    _.each(json, function(items) {
        _.each(items, function(item) {
            _.each(item, function(data) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (id === data.id) {
                        $('.removeLi').remove();
                        $('.spinner, .while-loads').fadeOut();
                        cardTemplate.push('<li><span class="name-role" id="name">' +
                            '<span><img class="card-picture" src="'+ data.picture +'"/></span>' +
                            '<div class="main-info-card">' +
                              data.name + '<br>' +
                              data.role + '<br>' +
                              'Employee N.' + data.id +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</span></li>' +
                        '<li><p>Email: <strong>'+ data.email +'</strong></p></li>' +
                        '<li><p>Skype: <strong>'+ data.skype +'</strong></p></li>' +
                        '<li><p class="team"> '+ data.account +' <br> <strong>Enterprise</strong></p></li>' +
                        '<li><strong> '+ data.location +'</strong></li>');

                        $('<ul/>', {
                            "class" : "removeLi",
                            html: cardTemplate.join('')
                        }).prependTo('.personal-info');

                        if ($('.removeLi').length) {
                            $('#sidebar li')
                            .first()
                            .css({'background': cardColor,
                                  'color': fontColor
                            });
                        }

                        if ($('.removeLi').length > 1 ) {
                            $('.removeLi').remove();
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

The result in the view:

[image]

Comment: I would like to see more of the code. In particular something that explains why you choose to use a timeout, and if you are calling this every time for a particular id.

Comment: @Sumurai8 look at my **EDIT** part and the image I pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is A LOT of code you have going on in multiple forEach loops. Need to partition out tasks.

1. Have a generic Function to Generate Cards
2. Have a Function to find users

Then combine them. This will help with DRY (Don't repeat yourself). So these can be reused on other parts of the application

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/disecezuwu/edit?js,console)

Here is a method to find the user based on Id, Im sure this could be cleaned and refactored more

```
function createCard(value, cb){
   var result;
    _.forEach(data, function(items){
    var results =_.filter(items[Object.keys(items)[0]], {'id' : value});
    if (results.length !== 0) result = results[0];
  });

  return _.isFunction(cb) ? cb(result) : result;
 }
```

Comment: for how long have you been programming? It took around an hour to understand it. Looks awesome and clean, thanks :)

Comment: About 10 years, Thank you. Also don't use timeouts. Implement Promises.  They won't drag your response time down like a setTimeout will.

Answer (score 1):

#### Naming, styling

Your function `compareId` does not name what the function actually does (show a popup card with information).

Variable declarations in javascript are hoisted to the top of their context. I recommend putting them there for clarity.

You are using a single `var`, and declare multiple variables using commas. I recommend against this, because omitting one comma, or having a semicolon will drop part of your variables in the global scope. It's easy to make such a mistake while adding or removing variables. Instead put `var` in front of every variable and close all statements with a `;`.

#### Potential bug

Since your code contains no comments, it is impossible for me to deduct what you want to happen in certain edge cases. Weirdly enough you have a piece of code that removes all results if you have more than one result. This is somewhat odd behaviour. Did you mean to remove everything except the first occurance of this class instead?

#### Performance

You are doing the same work over and over if you call `compareId` multiple times. You cannot get around doing all the work once, but for any subsequent calls you can already have prepared an intermediate data structure.

To do this, you can use two native functions:

Array.prototype.map

Map maps the current value of an Array to the new value by calling a specified function reference with the current value. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

Array.prototype.reduce

Reduce reduces an Array to a single value. Note that this single value **can** be anything, including an Array. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))

Possible implementation (in pseudo code)

```
var showCard = function(id) {
  var data;
  var credentials;

  if(this.processedData === undefined) {
    data = JSON.parse( ... );
    
    this.processedData = data.reduce(function(prev, cur) {

    }, []);
  }

  credentials = this.processedData[id];

  if( !credentials ) {
    //blah
  } else {
    //make html
    //put it in there
  }
  //--spinner
}
```